# Joda-Time: parse string

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a string

```
 String time = "2012-09-12 15:04:01";
```

I want to parse that string to [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTimeFormatter dateStringFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime time = dateStringFormat.parseDateTime(date);
```

But when I print time

```
time.toString()
```

The output is:

```
2012-09-12T15:04:01.000+03:00
```

Why output is different from input? What I do wrong? I mean what is 'T'??  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you parse a date or number you extra its value, not the format it was as a String.

When you toString() the value is converts it to a default format.

> Why output is different from input ?

It would be surprising coincidence if it were the same.

> What I doing wrong?

Assuming there is only one format of a value.

> I mean what is 'T' ?

It means it is in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

---

BTW you have the same problem with numbers

```
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("123456789"));
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("1.1e2"));
```

prints

```
1.23456789E8
110.0
```

In each case the value is correct, but original format is not recorded or preserved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want...

```
dateStringFormat.print(time);
```